# Returning Content-Type as application/javascript from a controller in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core

I am calling a third-party API that returns a Javascript function then I will have to send the returned function to my front-end application as a Javascript function. Here is my code:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> PrepareCheckOut(double Amount, string Currency, string UserId, int CourseId, int? CouponId, string OrderId)
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("www.cxcc.com");

            req.Method = "GET";
            req.Accept = "application/javascript";

            HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.ASCII);
            string responseString = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            myStreamReader.Close();
            responseStream.Close();
            myHttpWebResponse.Close();

            return Ok(responseString);
        }
```

However, my controller is returning content-type as plain text. I tried different ways to get the content type as application/javascript but nothing worked. Your help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is, you are setting the content type to the request object.

Try setting the content type to the response object instead, or set it directly with the `Content()` method:

```
return Content(responseString, "application/javascript");
```